# How to handle the BatchNorm layer when training fully convolutional networks by finetuning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, pytorch

Training fully convolutional nerworks (FCNs) for pixelwise semantic segmentation is very memory intensive. So we often use batchsize=1 for traing FCNs. However, when we finetune the pretrained networks with BatchNorm (BN) layers, batchsize=1 doesn't make sense for the BN layers. So, how to handle the BN layers?

Some options:

1. delete the BN layers (merge the BN layers with the preceding layers for the pretrained model)
2. Freeze the parameters and statistics of the BN layers
3. ....

which is better and any demo for implementation in pytorch/tf/caffe?

Answer (score 4):

Having only one element will make the batch normalization zero if epsilon is non-zero (variance is zero, mean will be same as input).
Its better to delete the BN layers from the network and try the activation function SELU (scaled exponential linear units). This is from the paper ['Self normalizing neural networks'](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02515.pdf) (SNNs).

Quote from the paper:

> While batch normalization requires explicit normalization, neuron
>   activations of SNNs automatically  converge  towards  zero  mean  and 
>   unit  variance.   The  activation function of SNNs are “scaled
>   exponential linear units” (SELUs), which induce self-normalizing
>   properties.

The SELU is defined as:

```
def selu(x, name="selu"):
  alpha = 1.6732632423543772848170429916717
  scale = 1.0507009873554804934193349852946
  return scale * tf.where(x >= 0.0, x, alpha * tf.nn.elu(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

[Batch Normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) was introduced to reduce the internal covariate shift of the input feature maps. Due to change of parameters of each layer after every optimization steps, input distribution of a layer also changes, this slow down the model convergence. By using Batch Normalization we can normalize the input distribution irrespective of the batch_size (whether batch_size =1 or larger).

> BN normalizes the input distribution

For convolutional network input for intermediate layer is 4D tensor. `[batch_size, width, height, num_filters]`. Normalization effect all the feature maps.

> delete the BN layers (merge the BN layers with the preceding layers for the pretrained model)

This may further slow down the training step and convergence mayn't be achieved.

> Freeze the parameters and statistics of the BN layers

Sometime the input data distribution for retrain/finetune, may vary significantly from the original data used to train the pretrained model used for initialization, Due to which your model may end-up in non-optimal solution.

Comment: A good point about BN for conv layers - even when batch size is one there is more than a single sample for averaging. Excellent observation!

Answer (score 2):

According to my experiments in PyTorch, if convolutional layer before the BN outputs more than one value (i.e. 1 x feat_nb x height x width, where height > 1 or width > 1), then the BN still works fine even when the batch size is equal to one. However, I suspect that in this case the variance estimate might be very biased since all samples that are used for variance calculation come from the same image. Therefore in my case I still decided to use small batch.

Answer (score 1):

[The effective batch size over convolutional layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxwfr.png)
I think the CNN-relative section (Section 3.2) in the BN original paper could help. From the point of view of the authors, it should be OK to use batch size = 1 for convolutional layers. The "effective batch size" for convolutional layer actually is batch_size * image_height * image_width.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an exact answer, but here are my thoughts:

---

> networks with BatchNorm (BN) layers, batchsize=1 doesn't make sense
>   for the BN layers

The main motivation of BN is to fix the distribution (mean/variance) of the input in the batch. In my opinion, having one element this does not make sense. [Judging from the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) [image]

you will need to calculate the mean and the variance for 1 element, which does not make sense.

---

You can always just remove BN but are you sure you can't afford at least 16 elements in the batch?

Comment: I'm not not sure BN is meaningless when batch size is one: the layer computes a moving average. So, leaving BN layers for fine tuning might make sense after all.

Comment: @Shai based on my understanding on the paper, you will need to calculate mean and the variance of the batch. Not sure how would you use the variance of 1 element (0)  in the next equation.

Comment: The variance of a single element can be tricky... (emoji of a thinking man).

Comment: @Shai this is exactly why I think that 1batch does not make sense (I might be wrong). If my understanding is wrong, would be happy to learn the correct way.

Comment: Maybe we can just freeze the BN layers (both the parameters and the moving averages) trained on ImageNet? Or we can use the setting like use_global_stats = 1 in caffe prototxt?

Answer (score 0):

My observation is in contrary with Stephan's: using PyTorch on a similar input `batch x feat_nb x height x width, where height > 1 or width > 1`, I found adding BatchNorm after the last conv and before the last non-linear (sigmoid) actually hurts the accuracy by a big margin. Still trying to make sense out of it..
(batch size = 8)